# check for existence of DOM selectors in html loaded via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I often use something like this:

```
if($('.mi-tn').length){
  alert('we got tasting notes');
}
```

to check for existence of class '.mi-tn' and then do some ajax calls. And

```
$('body').on('click','.another', function(){
```

for hooking up events to loaded html. How do I check for the existence of a class in loaded html so that I can fire off an ajax request?

### edit #1

here's a fiddle for trying to capture the mi-tn value http://jsfiddle.net/f59nZ/

### edit #2

```
  if($('body').find('.mi-tn').length){
    alert('gonna do ajax call but...');   
  }
```

Comment: can you share your html too? More helpful if you make [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with sample loaded html?

Comment: you're right thx @Unknown , I edited with fiddle

Comment: You've got a typo in that fiddle - ```.mi-tin``` instead of ```.mi-tn```. I'm not sure how much that is throwing you off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the one you are looking for?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#container').html("<div class='content'>here is some info<div class='mi-tn'></div>");  
    $(document).on('click','.content', function(){
        if($(this).find('.mi-tn').length){
           alert('gonna do ajax call but...');   
        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f59nZ/1/)**

If you dont need click event. You can use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#container').html("<div class='content'>here is some info<div class='mi-tn'></div>");  
    if($('.content').find('.mi-tn').length){
    alert('gonna do ajax call but...');   
  }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f59nZ/2/)

Comment: thx, so I don't really need the click event, I think I had tried edit #2 above but didn't seem to work. I wonder if there could be a concurrency issue with the above like it isn't fully in the DOM when the check is made.

Comment: yeah, I see that's working but.... Ugh, not working in my case. Do you know if find has some limit of DOM it will traverse in looking for an item? It's about 6 levels down in my real DOM.Or perhaps a timing thing

Comment: `.find()` should work even for 6 levels. Can you share sample with 6 levels just curious to see how it looks like?

Comment: thx, I edited it to this http://jsfiddle.net/f59nZ/3/  but it's working now. I think there was a single quote in the text which when I removed caused it to work. I thought that jquery's html escaped that. I'm also using Handlebars ... hmm.... seems like that's the issue